# Getting error while starting script/console or script/server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Error :

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- initializer (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:53:in `require'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:54:in `load_initializer'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:109
    from script/server:2:in `require'
    from script/server:2
```

Ruby 1.8.7

Rails 2.3.8

Rubgems 1.6.1

Any Idea !

Comment: try to update your Rails

Comment: Any other way ! I can't update Rails. I have to use Rails 2.3.8.

Comment: @flOOr I have updated to rails 2.3.11 still getting same error.

Comment: What was the last gem you have added to the project? try to remove it.

Comment: @Kleber I had installed list of different rails version(3.0.0,2.3.11,2.3.9). After uninstalling rails 3.0.0 it's working now. Removed all the 3.0.0 gems like actionmailer,activemodel,activeresource etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had installed list of different rails version(3.0.0,2.3.11,2.3.9). After uninstalling rails 3.0.0. Removed all the 3.0.0 gems like actionmailer,activemodel,activeresource etc. Application is working now.

Comment: Even if you think you are using bundler and a pre-3 version of rails, you might try `bundle exec rails -v` to confirm you have the version you expected.  With a variant of krunal's solution, I had to fix my Gemfile and bundler setup to get back to rails 2.3, where I thought I had been in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run ?

> bundle install

Well I'm not sure if this command even exists in rails 2.3. Let me know.

Comment: `Rails 2.3.8`. There is no any bundle

Comment: fl00r: No one stopping you from using Bundler with 2.3.x. We do it too for our app.